# Variable doesn't exist: contactid

Tags: trigger

I am trying to refer the element(`listname.contactid`) from the list but I am getting error:

> Variable doesn't exist error

However I am getting the entire list when I just use list name.

I know I that I am doing something wrong.

Can someone please help me solve this guide me to learn the cause of the this. 
Thank you. Code is given below.

---

```
trigger dlrs_CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember(after delete, after insert) {

    list campaignlist = new list();
    set cmpId = new set();
    if (trigger.isDelete) { //system.debug(trigger.old); 
        for (CampaignMember campMem: trigger.old) {
            CampaignMember cpm = new CampaignMember();
            cpm.CampaignId = campMem.CampaignId;
            cpm.contactid = campmem.contactid;
            cpm.LeadId = campmem.LeadId;
            campaignlist.add(cpm); //error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(CampaignMember) from the type CampaignMember 
            cmpId.add(campMem.CampaignId);
            system.debug(campaignlist);
            system.debug(campaignlist.contactid); //---- error Variable doesn't exist: contactid 
        }
        campaign[] campname = [select name from campaign where Id in: cmpId];
        system.debug(campname);

    }
}
```

Comment: system.debug(campaignlist); //result give below

|DEBUG|campaignlist(CampaignMember:{CampaignId=7011s0000008xLWAAY, ContactId=0031s000001XZ7gAAG, LeadId=null})

Comment: You seem to lack the basic of List and Set, I would suggest to learn the basic on trailhead (like [Getting started with Apex Unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro)) and look at error closely.

Comment: Thank you for the Guidance Rahul.

Comment: it would be unusual to have to edit a DLRS trigger as these are generated by the DLRS package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I can understand from your code is you are trying to access contactId from a List type variable.

```
system.debug(campaignlist.contactid); //---- error Variable doesn't exist:
```

You need to iterate through campaignList and then access the contactid like below:

```
for(CampaignMember cmp :campaignlist){
   cmp.contactId;
   system.debug('contact id '+cmp.contactId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code, my recommendation is to study more...

```
trigger dlrs_CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember (after delete, after insert) {

    list<CampaignMember> campaignlist = new list<CampaignMember>(); //right way to declare a list
    set<ID> cmpId = new set<ID>(); // right way to declare a set
    if (trigger.isDelete) { //system.debug(trigger.old); 
        for (CampaignMember campMem: trigger.old) {
            CampaignMember cpm = new CampaignMember();
            cpm.CampaignId = campMem.CampaignId;
            cpm.contactid = campmem.contactid;
            cpm.LeadId = campmem.LeadId;
            campaignlist.add(cpm); //error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(CampaignMember) from the type CampaignMember 
            cmpId.add(campMem.CampaignId);
            system.debug(campaignlist);
            system.debug(cpm.contactid); //right way to get the ContactID
        }
        string campname = [select name from campaign where Id in: cmpId limit 1].name; //right way to get the Campaign Name
        system.debug(campname);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Peixoto. I will study more. Have a great day.